# Items Out of Stock. even though they have been just added

Tags: magento-1.9, stock, ce-1.9.2.2, out-of-stock

I realized that our latest added list of products that been just uploaded disappeared from our front-end. So I checked Magento, and the all those products had their stock at "zero" even though they just have been "replenished".

what could be causing this? and how should I solve this issue?

Comment: check the index settings

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a comprehensive guide to this covered by ASchroder:

[Why are my Magento products not showing up?!](http://www.aschroder.com/2010/07/why-are-my-magento-products-not-showing-up/)

Check your store's default configuration for stock management via:

`System` → `Configuration` → `Catalog` → `Inventory`

Under the `Stock Options` section, you'll see the setting for `Display Out of Stock Products`, which in your case is likely set to no.

Under the `Product Stock Options`, you are able to see your default setting for Manage Stock & Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock.

I'd assume that due to the products being stock managed & out of stock, they're no longer visible on the frontend.

Remember to refresh your caches & re-index after changing configuration & stock options to ensure that the updates are visible on the frontend.